# Is the range of labels important for scikit classifiers?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I could not find an answer for my question anywhere.

Let's say I am going to make a classification with from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier. Should the classes need to be integers (and if so do they have to start from 0 or 1 ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the classes can be any discrete values.

1. They can be strings as in ['yes', 'no'] or ['high', 'medium', 'low']
2. Integers like [4, 5, 10] or [1, 2, 3] or [-1, 1]

Internally, they will be converted to integers starting from 0, using [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). You don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score -2):

The standard approach is to model classes via [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)

Comment: But one-hot encoding this is obviously not required here, the doc of `SGDClassifier` has an example where the targets are `Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])`.